# how to make a Text view support dictionary services in OSX

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to use apple's Dictionary service in my app. the test code is like the following. It can get the word's expound, the question is :
1.how to get the offset in func DCSGetTermRangeInString, I set to 7 in my code 
2.how to let Text view response to keyboard event cmd+ctrl+d

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  testTextClick
//
//  Created by lezi on 2020/6/2.
//  Copyright © 2020 lezi. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import AppKit
import CoreServices.DictionaryServices

struct ContentView: View {
    let txt = "hello world"
    var body: some View {

        VStack{

            Text(txt)
                .contextMenu(){
                    Button("search xxx"){
                       let range = DCSGetTermRangeInString(nil, self.txt as CFString, 7)
                        let str = DCSCopyTextDefinition(nil,self.txt as CFString ,range)
                        print(str)
                    }
            }

        }
            .frame(maxWidth:.infinity,maxHeight: .infinity)



    }


}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the NSTextView is exposed more function to do this work.

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {


    let location = event.locationInWindow
    let point3 = self.window?.convertPoint(toScreen: location)
    let idx = self.characterIndex(for: point3!)
    let range = DCSGetTermRangeInString(nil, self.string as CFString, idx)
   super.mouseDown(with: event)

}
```